# Deploying Django project on Linux

Tags: python, mysql, django

Comming from PHP(without frameworks), I don't quite understand how deploying works in Python. I have completed my simple Django version: *(1, 10, 1, 'final', 1)* blog project and all I have to do is put it online. I am using linux openSUSE distro and virtualenv

I have access to a mysql database with phpmyadmin and I have some space, accessed with filezilla. hosting site: *https://host.bg/*

But then I started researching of how to deploy my project and I stumbled upon stuf like apache, Nginx, wsgi and other stuff I haven't used in the project and not quite familiar how they work.

So my question is: Can I make my project into a folder with some files in it, copy->paste them in filezilla and have a working site and if not, how does django deployment really work and what should I do from here ?!

Comment: May be this help you... [Setup Django on Apache and WSGI](http://sparkanswers.com/setup-django-on-apache-and-wsgi/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Git instead of FTP protocol. As you are using Linux you can easily connect to your SO using ssh.

About the deployment, I would recommend you to use GUnicorn for a WSGI way.
It's not hard to deploy with, but if you get in trouble you can use the official Django documentation for deploying Django with WSGI:

[Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/)

Ps.: As you are using Linux, I would recommend to you to use VirtualEnv to allow you server many Django sites in the same Linux instance with the isolated environments

Answer (score 1):

Check what version of Python is installed on the server hosting your account and if there's option for ssh access.

Host.bg and Bulgarian hosting providers in general fail to keep up with most things other than php and mysql. With shared plans they avoid installing anything new too.

I'd say contact support and see if they would be able to assist you with Apache configurations and whatever else is needed for your project.